# File deletes content after stopping execution in C

Tags: c, file-handling

So I'm trying to save a bunch of data in a text file to load it later.
The function prints the data to the text file correctly, but when I stop the execution and start it again to see if it loads, there is no data in the text file.
It happens right after I stop the program.

Here is the function used:

```
void saveGame(t_game game, int width, int height){
FILE * file= fopen("save.txt", "w+");
int i = 0;
int j = 0;

fprintf(file,"%d%d", game.origbomb, game.wincount);

for(i=0;i<width;i++){
    for(j=0;j<height;j++){
        fprintf(file,"%c",game.map[i][j]);
    }
}
for(i=0;i<width;i++){
        for(j=0;j<height;j++){
            fprintf(file,"%c",game.bombmap[i][j]);
        }
    }
fclose(file);}
```

Comment: Debugging 101: test one thing at a time. If your read doesn't see your write, you don't know which one is broken. Do your write, then look at the file with something else, like a text editor or just cat. If the file looks good, then it's the read that's broken,

Comment: `fscanf(file,"%d%d", &game.origbomb, &game.wincount);` this is an interesting format.  How does the scanning differentiate between a 3 x 12 and a 31 x 2 map?  Won't both look like `312` in the file?

Comment: The the function seems right. It writes what it's suposed to write, but it doesn't "save". So when the execution stops, the file goes empty. EDIT: the numbers I save will NEVER go past 9

Comment: Then it's not writing, is it? Keep debugging: print out the filename. Is it what you expect? What's the return value from the fprintf call? ...

Comment: If this is doing what it looks like you're doing, you may actually want "r+", not "a+".

Comment: As @jpo38 said, changing w+ to a+ adds data at the end of the file. With w+ it actually rewrites everything written before. I may want to use r+ to later load the data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use:

```
FILE * file= fopen("save.txt", "a+");
```

This will append to the file.

Answer (score 1):

If you "stop the execution", then I suppose `fclose` was not called, then only flushed data will be present in the file. Use `fflush` to manually force the file content to be flushed just after you called `fprintf`.

Also, consider checking file content from a file editor rather than a program. Maybe you are not reading it correctly.

Finally, consider opening the file with "a" option if you mean to extend an existing content without creating a new file.